# Python, list of tuples split into dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples as shown:

```
lt = [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(3,'b'),(3,'c')]
```

I want to make the numbers keys of a dictionary and have them point to a list. That list then holds all associations in the list of tuples. So in the list above, it would split into a dictionary as:

```
dict_lt:{
1:[a,b],
2:[a],
3:[b,c]
}
```

Currently I use the dictionary's flexibility in automatically declaring new keys, which I then force point to an empty list. Then I fill that list accordingly.

```
dict_lt = {}

for tup in lt:
   dict_lt[tup[0]] = []

for tup in lt:
   dict_lt[tup[0]].append(tup[1])
```

This works fine, but its a tad slow since it needs to iterate twice over the same list, and it just seems overall redundant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to iterate the list twice. You can use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set the initial value if the key is not in the dictionary:

```
lt = [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(3,'b'),(3,'c')]
d = {}
for k, v in lt:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(d)
```

**prints**

```
{1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `list` factory or `dict.setdefault` to create a list that you can append the values to.

**`collections.defaultdict`**:

```
out = collections.defaultdict(list) 

for k, v in lt: 
    out[k].append(v)
```

**`dict.setdefault`**:

```
out = {} 

for k, v in lt: 
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

**Example:**

```
In [11]: lt = [(1, 'a'),(1, 'b'),(2, 'a'),(3, 'b'),(3, 'c')]                                                                                                                                                

In [12]: out = {}                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [13]: for k, v in lt: 
    ...:     out.setdefault(k, []).append(v) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [14]: out                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[14]: {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['b', 'c']}

In [15]: out = collections.defaultdict(list)                                                                                                                                                                

In [16]: for k, v in lt: 
    ...:     out[k].append(v) 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [17]: out                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[17]: defaultdict(list, {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['b', 'c']})
```

Comment: A note on performance: If you're doing this a lot, especially if the number of unique keys is small relative to the total number of pairs, using `collections.defaultdict(list)` is *much* better, for two reasons: 1) 90% of the time (and this case is in the 90%), using a method call is slower than an equivalent operation supported by syntax; being able to do `d[k]` is faster than `d.get(k)` or `d.setdefault(k, None)` so long as `d[k]` won't raise `KeyError`. 2) `setdefault(k, [])` must create an empty `list` *every* time, even when the key exists; `defaultdict` only creates one when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict(list)` in your code instead of `dict`, and just omit the first loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_lt = defaultdict(list)


for tup in lt:
    dict_lt[tup[0]].append(tup[1])
```